# using onmouseover to change text hyperlink into an image hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

Please bear with me I am brand new to learning javascript (self taught)! I am usually one to find answers on my own from just web browsing but so far I haven't found any resources explaining how to accomplish the following:

So, basically all I want to do is change this (HTML):

```
<a href="link.html"id="speaker"onmouseover="showImage()"onmouseout="goBack()">SPEAKERS</a>
```

to an image by using javascript.

The image is kept in the same folder as the html and the js.
Here is as far as I know to go with the javascript:

```
function showImage()
 {   
 picture = new Image(100,100);
picture.src = "icon2.png";
document.getElementById("speakers").innerHTML = picture.src;
  }

function goBack()
 {   
 document.getElementById("speakers").innerHTML="SPEAKERS";
 }
```

For clarity, all I would like to do is change the text ("SPEAKERS") to an image using 'onmouseover' while using the same hyperlink in the process.

It seems like a very simple problem but I don't know enough to determine if what I want to do is even possible. If it's not possible that's fine, I would just like to know either way ;P. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: @davidbusatto: I haven't learned jQuery yet so no lol. If I need to learn jQuery to do this then please let me know. I don't want to waste anyones time.

Comment: You don't need to learn jquery, but if you want to try it I've included a jquery option below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with using jquery, you could use `.html()` and `.hover()`

http://jsfiddle.net/u8fsU/

Comment: I think my web browser might be a fault. I checked out the fiddle and when I mouseover the "SPEAKERS" just disapears. No image :(.

Comment: It's possible your browser just didn't load the image in time. It would be cached in my browser but not in yours. IE7 would still work with this.

Comment: Well it sounds like I need to learn jQuery then. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get you started (not a complete nor tested solution):

```
var showImage = function(){
  var picture = document.createElement("img");
  picture.src = "icon2.png";
  picture.href = "link.html";

  var speakers = document.getElementById("speakers");
  speakers.parentNode.replaceChild(speakers, picture);
}
```

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference for a good reference to some of the available DOM properties and methods.

Comment: It looks like it would work... but it doesn't even change the SPEAKERS? Could my web browser be a factor? I'm using IE7?